# Find error line in AngularJS app

Tags: debugging, angularjs

I just started to play with AngularJS and I got error below.

```
Error: Argument '?' is not a function, got Object
at assertArg (http://localhost/angular/project/scripts/vendor/angular.js:1039:11)
at assertArgFn (http://localhost/angular/project/scripts/vendor/angular.js:1049:3)
at http://localhost/angular/project/scripts/vendor/angular.js:4802:9
at http://localhost/angular/project/scripts/vendor/angular.js:4384:17
at forEach (http://localhost/angular/project/scripts/vendor/angular.js:137:20)
at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost/angular/project/scripts/vendor/angular.js:4369:11)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost/angular/project/scripts/vendor/angular.js:4015:15)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost/angular/project/scripts/vendor/angular.js:4018:13)
at publicLinkFn (http://localhost/angular/project/scripts/vendor/angular.js:3920:30)
at update (http://localhost/angular/project/scripts/vendor/angular.js:14202:11)
```

Now, my question is: Is there a way I can find line in .js file where error occurred?
I get line number in angular.js file on raised exception but there is too many files where 
error can occur.

I tried with AngularJS Batarang, but this is more for debugging semantic not syntax errors.

Thanks.

Comment: Experience helps here; after a while you know where to look first for errors like these that aren't very expressive. The issue you raise is a good one, though. And I don't know of a way to do it right now :( Also, Batarang won't be any help here. It's main use is in inspecting scope inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

It'll be easier if you link to the js files that would have caused this error.

From the angular.js source, https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js
it looks like a problem with instantiating the controller.

Here's the line that's causing assertion failure:

```
/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name ng.$controller
 * @requires $injector
 *
 * @param {Function|string} constructor If called with a function then it's considered to be the
 *    controller constructor function. Otherwise it's considered to be a string which is used
 *    to retrieve the controller constructor using the following steps:
 *
 *    * check if a controller with given name is registered via `$controllerProvider`
 *    * check if evaluating the string on the current scope returns a constructor
 *    * check `window[constructor]` on the global `window` object
 *
 * @param {Object} locals Injection locals for Controller.
 * @return {Object} Instance of given controller.
 *
 * @description
 * `$controller` service is responsible for instantiating controllers.
 *
 * It's just a simple call to {@link AUTO.$injector $injector}, but extracted into
 * a service, so that one can override this service with {@link https://gist.github.com/1649788
 * BC version}.
 */
return function(constructor, locals) {
  if(isString(constructor)) {
    var name = constructor;
    constructor = controllers.hasOwnProperty(name)
        ? controllers[name]
        : getter(locals.$scope, name, true) || getter($window, name, true);
```

======> assertArgFn(constructor, name, true);
      }

```
  return $injector.instantiate(constructor, locals);
};
```

It's unable to find the constructor for the controller.

Comment: Yes, you`re right I omitted controller name `<div ng-controller=""`. But that is not really why I asked. File with omitted controller name is LoginWin.html, and I`m curious is there any way I can get error message that points to file with error.

Comment: Why has no one upvoted this?
In the past I never needed the line number, because I intrinsically knew my code to know where an issue would have occured.
However trying to integrate code from one system to another I now need much better information from the errors in the console and angular is being useless.